# Use client-side script to set Business Process Flow Stage on Opportunity in Dynamics CRM

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I'm working in Dynamics CRM 2015 Online and need to apply some conditional rule to the Opportunity when it is first created from a Lead qualification.  Under certain conditions we need to automatically advance the Business Process Flow stage to the second stage in the flow.  I've already tried this using variations of a plugin on Opportunity Create to set the stage id, but it seems that any value I assign there is ignored when the Opportunity is created from a Lead.  Right now I'm trying to fire a javascript function during the Opportunity Form OnLoad event.  One catch here is I'm also working against a field that is business required but not filled in when the Opportunity is created from a Lead so I can't do a simple `Xrm.Page.data.process.moveNext()` in the script.  Instead I am updating the Opportunity using the JQuery SDK function updateRecord that is part of the CRM SDK scripts. Here's the important bits of the code:

```
opp = {
   OpportunityId: oppId,
   StageId: newProcessStageId
}

SDK.JQuery.updateRecord(
   oppId,
   opp,
   "Opportunity",
   function () {
      // success, refresh the form
      Xrm.Page.data.refresh();
   },
   function (error) {
      alert("An error occurred while updating the opportunity: " + error.description);
   }
);
```

This does work to change the stage, however the problem is on the form the Business Process Flow still shows the first stage as the selected stage, even though it moved the flag indicating the active stage is stage 2, as seen in this screenshot:

[image]

After the update, I do a refresh of the form data, but I don't see any way to set the "selected" stage to match the new active stage.  I've scoured the SDK docs and searched around but can't find anything that will do this.  Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Unrequire the the required field on load in order to change the stage.  Then try to move to the next stage.

Comment: As an alternative to the process described in my original post, I did also try switching the required field to optional, and then did a `Xrm.Page.data.process.moveNext()` however I was getting unexpected behavior from that.  The response from that call was "dirtyForm" even though nothing else had changed.  I tried issuing a save and form refresh first and still get the "dirtyForm" response from that.  That behavior is not correct based on the SDK documents relating to these functions, so at the moment that isn't an option either.

Answer (score 0):

What if you do a `Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm()` call instead of a data.refresh?  (BTW, I've been trying to find a way to set selected stage in JS for a while as well, and haven't found anything either.  I do think if you completely reload the form instead of just the data, though, it should set the selected to the active.)